# Dapper (connection.Query or connection.Execute)

Tags: stored-procedures, execute, dapper

I see the example of using Dapper in executing stored procedures with dynamic parameters, and returning the results of the procedure.  Usually, the examples use .Execute, but a few of them use .Query.  I have difficulty in using .Execute.  Which am I supposed to use in the case described above--query or execute AND in what cases would I use each?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to return a value, then use Query(). If you need to execute a query that does not return anything, an update for example, then use Execute().

Query example:

```
var myList = connection.Query("select * from myTable")
```

Execute example:

```
connection.Execute("update myTable set columnA = @value", new {value = "ABC"})
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Execute() returns the number of rows affected.